# Run two graphic cards in SLI with a Y-Power-Splitter

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply

I bought a new [MSI Z97S SLI Krait](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/Z97S-SLI-Krait-Edition) mainboard with two `PCI-E` slots.

Because i bought a [GeForce GTX 770 MSI OC](http://msi.com/Graphics-card/N770-TF-2GD5OC.html#hero-overview) two years ago, I bought another one very cheap to let them run in `SLI` mode.

But i discovered that my power adapter has only 2 PCI-E power slots..

Is it possible to double the `PCI-E Power` (Y-Splitter like [this](http://www.frozencpu.com/products/8252/cab-148/8-pin_PCI-E_to_2x_PCI-E_8pin_Y_cable.html)) to connect both GPUs with this [PSU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_supply_unit_(computer)): [Sharkoon WPM (700W)](http://sharkoon.com/product/1188/WPMBronze#specs) **without any risk of damaging one of my components**!

> My GPU requires 2 PCI-E powers connectors **each**, my PSU, has 2 PCI-E Power connectors in total.

Comment: Running a PSUs in Parallel does not do what you think it does.  *The cable you link of course does not create a Parallel circuit.*  Why is there a random link to urban dictionary?  Why are you linking to the PSU Wikipedia, you know what a PSU is, seems unnecessary.

Comment: @Ramhound sorry i forgot to remove the parrallel thing, i just want to power both graphic cards. --- I don't know if anybody knows the therm `SFMBE` ;)

Comment: Why do people apologize for their "English", either fix the grammar yourself using the appropriate tools, or say nothing and let somebody else do it.  Why bring attention to it?  Remove the "thanks' its not required.

Comment: Using the cable will not "double" the power but it will accomplish what you need to do.

Comment: @Ramhound did you check my PSU? I don't know if it has enougth power. If you answer to this questions i can accept your answer if you want, but please justify it

Comment: I am not going to answer this question.  You can self-answer it.  I am not going to determine if your PSU, can provide enough power, to both of those GPUs you can determine that yourself.  You wanted to know if the cable would achieve your goals, that I can answer, since that requires experience.  Determine the maximum power requirements for each card by themselves, the sum of those two numbers, plus the power requirements for all other components will determine if a 700W PSU is enough.  *I don't have your hardware in front of me, so I can't do those calculations, only you can do that.*

Comment: You can use something like [this](http://outervision.com/power-supply-calculator) to estimate your needs.

Comment: @Ramhound yeah I know that 700W is enought. But i have no idea what is the maximum power one PCI-E pin can provide. I don't want my PSU to melt because I used 4 pins where only 2 slots are. Also I don't know if the cable is strong enouth. -- This tool is amazing! Thank you

Comment: Your real problem is that a single card requires 2 PCI-E power connections it seems.  I didn't realize a single card required 2 connectors itself, that changes a great deal, you need a different PSU.  Your PSU will not provide stable power, the GPUs question, will not be stable in a SLI configuration.

Comment: @Ramhound why can't i connect one card to one port and split the power to the two connections needed?

Comment: [Your PSU cannot supply enough Amperage](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2091648/gtx-770-sli-power-supply-requirements.html).  Your PSU, to be blunt, is a bottom of the barrel brand.  The link in this answer explains it best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 770 GTX has a TDP of around 230 Watts which means it pulls around 19 A on a +12 V rail.  If you have two 770 GTXs then you need more then 38 A in a SLI configuration on the +12 V rail.

[image]

Your [Sharkoon WPM (700W)](http://sharkoon.com/product/1188/WPMBronze#specs) while it does provide, 54 A on the 12 V rail, that likely isn't enough if you consider the other components.

What you want is a PSU which has at least 2 12 V rails, with each rail providing at least 19 A, allowing you to connect one GPU to each rail.  This means at least 750 W PSU, with two @20A 12V rails would be required.

The max combined power of your PSU is 648 W.  You are looking at 460 W just for the GPUs by themselfs.  This would leave 188 W for the rest of the system.

Comment: Are those 54A combined **or** for each rail? Is a try worth it or could it damage my PSU?

Comment: Your PSU only has a single 12V rail.

Comment: I don't believe splitting the PCI-E cables, while it would be perfectly safe to do so, is a viable option because of close the amperage would be in the end.  You have to consider all the other components in the system, I don't have that information, so I can't do those calculations.  I also have my doubts splitting the PCI-E cables would even work, even if your PSU, provided enough amperage on a single rail.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your information. It helped me out a lot ;)